# Pip is searching other requirement file than I wish

Tags: pip, conda

I am trying to install dependencies from requirements .txt but I am encountering an error.

Command used:

`$ pip install -r requirements.txt`

This is result:

`ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements-common.txt'`

I made sure that the file "requirements.txt" is present. I  tried both absolute and relative paths but I'm encountering the same result.

Comment: I'd imagine `requirements.txt` contains the line `-r requirements-common.txt`.

Comment: That is what I am thinking .. you could just rename requirements.txt to requirements-common.txt and see what happens?  ren requirements.txt requirements-common.txt ( <-- thats the command line for this)

Comment: Yes, I have found it just after writing the question. Probably I had needed to focus mind on something different. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for dummy question, I haven't known that it is possible to refer other requirement files within the original requirement file.
My requirements.txt include:
`-r requirements-common.txt` which pip is searching for.